# Moment.js - formatting an existing time?

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I am using moment.js to work with dates and times in node.js.  So far I've been able to do everything I need with it, but I am having problems formatting a time.

Here's the scenario:

User enters data (an integer), which is logged in a database, along with date (in the format YYYY-MM-DD) and time (in the format HH:MM:SS).

Next time the user goes to enter data, the previous value is read in and compared (higher, lower or equal to) the new value.  However I also want to display a message such as "The last time you submitted your data was at TIME on DATE".  In this case, I'd like time to be displayed in a different format (e.g. "h:mm a" i.e. "12:34 pm").

Can I use moment to format an existing date, or can moment only return current date/time?  In my code I have the following function:

```
function userFormattedTime(time)
{
    let uTime = moment(time).format('h:mm a');
    return uTime
}
```

However when I call this function and pass it the time (taken from the database), I get "Invalid Time".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a sample value of `time` parameter? Probably your input is not in format recognized by [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) (ISO 8601 or RFC 2822), so you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would parse the string from a string back to a moment object, then you can use moment to reformat the date into any other format.

I guess what you are doing wrong is not telling moment what you're sending it back, i.e. it doesn't understand the formatted string you're supplying.

Notice the format values HH:mm:ss which vary in case. The case is important and should be set to match your requirements. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

```
// Original date time string
var rawDateTime = "02-02-2018 10:20:30";

// convert string to a moment object
var originalDate = moment(rawDateTime, "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss");

// Format a new string from the moment object
var newFormattedString = originalDate.format('h:mm a');
```

In order to calculate the difference of moment objects you can use the diff function. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

```
// Two different dates
var dateOne = moment("02-02-2018 10:20:30", "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
var dateTwo = moment("04-04-2018 10:20:30", "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss");

// Get the difference of the two dates
var diff = dateOne.diff(dateTwo);
```

Comment: OK I'll give this a try!

Comment: I've just noticed that you also wanted to get the difference between two values i.e. higher, lower and equal. The diff function of moment is good for this: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try too!

Comment: OK, your suggestion for parsing the date seems to be working!  Thanks very much!